# Mongo java api ignores nested or/and operators

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to search for person by: name AND ( document OR birthdate).

Seems rather simple, but my query doens't return anything.
Program runs without errors, but 0 records found.
If I remove or and search by name only, it works.

```
List<Bson> fullname = new ArrayList<>();
List<Bson> bd = new ArrayList<>();

bd.add(eq("by", 1999));
bd.add(eq("bm", 9));
bd.add(eq("bd", 18));

fullname.add(eq("l", ln));
fullname.add(eq("f", fn));
fullname.add(eq("p", pn));

Bson filter = and(
                    and(fullname),
                    or(
                            eq(and(bd)),
                            eq("document", document)
                    )
            );
```

Maybe there is a better syntax for such queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your variable naming, this should be:

```
 Bson filter = and(
                and(fullname),
                or(
                        and(bd),                  // no "eq" here
                        eq("document", document)
                )
        );
```